# Seeking resources that explain options for Python syntax

Tags: python

I have noticed the varying syntax that can be used in python. For example, the following two regex statements are identical:

```
matches = re.finditer(pattern, text_to_search)]                              
matches = pattern.finditer(text_to_search)
```

Why does Python allow these two statements? Where can I learn more about the varying syntax options?

Comment: Those are **not** distinct syntactically. It also only works in both cases if `pattern` is a compiled `re.Pattern` object; `re.finditer(pattern, text_to_search)` works if `pattern` is a *string* too.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) is always a good place to start looking.

Comment: in response to jonrsharpe: What do you mean they are not distinct syntactically? They are written differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just something you have to know about the Python `re` standard library module, and it's a good thing...

Generally, if you're going to use a regex more than once or twice, then you are better of compiling it to a `Pattern` object and then making calls on that object, as you avoid multiple compiles of the same expression. Another advantage is that you can specify flags on the Pattern object and otherwise configure it, and you only have to do so once.

But if you only want to use a regex once, then Python offers you calls on the `re` module itself as a shortcut that avoids you having to first create a `Pattern` object and then make a call on it to use it.

If you look at the regex documentation, you will find many such pairs of methods with the same name, one on the `Pattern` object and one on the `re` package itself, where the only difference in arguments is that the `re` version takes an extra argument, a `pattern` as its first argument.

Now what you're questioning is the case where you've created a Pattern object in either case, and are just noting that you can use both methods with that object.  The key thing here is that in your first example call, `pattern` can be a string, whereas in the second it has to be a `Pattern` object.  It's for the case where you're passing in a string that the `re` versions of each method really exist.  You've just found a loophole of sorts.  As far as I know, there is no advantage of one over the other in your case, if `pattern` is a Pattern object in both cases.  The second version is the usual way a `Pattern` object is applied.  The first is not so commonly used.  So I'd recommend the second form.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Python language feature, but a library feature.

One could, for example:

1. Create a class named `Point`, defined as

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

2. Create a function named `distance_to`, defined as

```py
def distance_to(point_1, point_2):
    dx = point_1.x - point_2.x
    dy = point_1.y - point_2.y
    return (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5
```

3. Create a method named `distance_to` in the `Point` class, defined as

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance_to(self, other):
        return distance_to(self, other)
```

So you have two ways to find a distance between two points: a `Point` method or a global function.

```py
p0 = Point(0, 0)
p1 = Point(1, 1)

# first way
print(distance_to(p0, p1))    # prints 1.41421

# second way
print(p0.distance_to(p1))     # prints 1.41421
```

Note that declaring these versions are optional, so when creating a library (in your case, `re`), the programmer must decide whether or not should have only one way to do something. One way to find out these alternative declarations is by looking at the docs.